# I inverted 2 digits to a wallet in a transfer

Tags: transactions

Is there anyway to contact the wallet owner to retrieve the coins?  If the wallet doesn't exist, can the transaction be reversed?  Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: What produce or service were you using the make the transfer? Do you mean two digits in the receiver's bitcoin address?

Answer (score -1):

- Normally a Bitcoin address is in the Base58Check or Bech32 format. Both of these formats have a checksum incorporated specifically designed so that wallets can detect if there is a typo in the address. It is strange that the wallet allowed you to submit the transaction.
- There is no way to contact the owner of a wallet that can spend a specific Transaction Output (coins)
- Transactions cannot be reversed. Under no circumstances. Even if you can proove that you are the owner.

BUT!!!
As we speak, October 30, 2020

The mempool is full, allegedly because miners in China are moving due to the rainy season. So the hash power has dropped and many low fee transactions have not been processed yet.
So, use a blockchain explorer to check if your transaction has been processed.
If not, then you can try to double-spend it by providing a higher fee for miners.
Higher fee transactions are processed first.

Comment: Most of your response is at best completely irrelevant.